# Differences between SFMC Audience Builder and DMP's user segmentation?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there any key difference between SFMC Audience Builder and DMP when it comes to user segmentation?

Say for the below scenario (for both DMP & Audience Builder)

- Any limitation in then number of records being processed?
- What is the refresh rate? I understand in DMP it is configurable but how about in Audience builder?

Apart from these, are there any major differences between these 2 when I look forward to segment user data?